# Why is not building package turtlebot3_gazebo on ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2, build-package, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I work with a turtlebot3 burger. In the instructions, when I install packages,
http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/ros2_setup/#pc-setup (16.1.4)

```
mkdir -p ~/turtlebot3_ws/src

cd ~/turtlebot3_ws

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/ros2/turtlebot3.repos

vcs import src < turtlebot3.repos

colcon build --symlink-install
```

the following error occurs:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findgazebo_ros_pkgs.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "gazebo_ros_pkgs", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo_ros_pkgs"
  with any of the following names:

    gazebo_ros_pkgsConfig.cmake
    gazebo_ros_pkgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gazebo_ros_pkgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "gazebo_ros_pkgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "gazebo_ros_pkgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.


---
Failed   <<< turtlebot3_gazebo [ Exited with code 1 ]
                                 
Summary: 12 packages finished [9.23s]
  1 package failed: turtlebot3_gazebo
  1 package had stderr output: turtlebot3_gazebo
  1 package not processed
```

I work with ROS2 Dashing Diademata and it work fine. Installing package Gazebo9.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349782/why-is-not-building-package-turtlebot3_gazebo-on-ros2?/) by [aktec](https://answers.ros.org/users/53693/aktec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-04-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That’s the classic “you didn’t install that package” error. Make sure to install it and/or run rosdep.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bishaljais](https://answers.ros.org/users/63540/bishaljais/) on 2020-11-23**:
I had already installed gazebo still it shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must install the gazebo-ros package

sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-gazebo-ros

change melodic for your ros version

---

Originally posted by [Yesika Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/52585/yesika-rodriguez/) with karma: 11 on 2020-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1